# elasticsearch time series data aggregation reverse countdown

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in elasticsearch whose records looks like:

```
{
      checkat: 2019-11-01,
      imei: "123",
      version: "abc"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-02,
      imei: "123",
      version: "def"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-02,
      imei: "456",
      version: "ghi"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-03,
      imei: "123",
      version: "ghi"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-03,
      imei: "456",
      version: "ghi"
}
```

How to represent a chart where query is :

```
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": {
                    "range": {
                      "checkat": {
                        "gte": "2019-11-01",
                        "lte": "2019-11-03"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

[image]

Because the previous day count is erased by the next day count.

Is it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a new index that only takes the latest version saved for each IMEI

`{
      checkat: 2019-11-01,
      imei: "123",
      version: "abc"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-02,
      imei: "123",
      version: "def"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-02,
      imei: "456",
      version: "ghi"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-03,
      imei: "123",
      version: "ghi"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-03,
      imei: "456",
      version: "ghi"
}`

Merge done by Logstash make that :

`{
      checkat: 2019-11-03,
      imei: "123",
      version: "ghi"
},
{
      checkat: 2019-11-03,
      imei: "456",
      version: "ghi"
}`